# Making a custom mattermost client with Flutter, but login headers do not return the necessary headers

Tags: flutter, dart, mattermost

**Summary**

Cannot get headers [“Set-Cookie”] when login into the system with custom login

**Steps to reproduce**

Use Postman, try to login to workspace with your credentials, view headers. You will not see the “Set-Cookie”

**Expected behavior**

Request headers should have the “Set-Cookie” headers.

**Observed behavior**

Request headers does not have the “Set-Cookie” headers.

**Extra info for context**

Im currently developing a custom app for our company using mattermost as the backbone. I created the login and moved on to design the rest of the app, when I went to start making api request all of them would fail. After checking the web client to verify why they were failing, I saw the login had the “set-cookie” headers and they would be used in every request. There I understood my problem.

I needed the set-cookies for every request, so I went and checked the request headers in the app response headers and saw that they were not there. After that I tried with a custom backend that would do the request, same not there. After that I went to postman and same. Without the data in the set-cookies I can’t continue.

Any help would be appreciated,